# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^{2016} e^x}{e^x + 1} \ dx$ by splitting the definite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The full question is as follows:

Using
$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{a} \left(f(x) + f(-x)\right)dx$, find exact value of the integral $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} \ dx$$

Applying the identity given, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} \ dx &= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} + \frac{(-x)^{2016}e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1}\right)dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} + \frac{x^{2016}e^{x}}{e^{x}+1}\right) dx \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} \ dx
\end{align*}

I am stuck after this step. Trying various substitutions for $u = e^x$, $u = e^x + 1$ did not seem to work as well.

Is there a mistake in the preliminary steps shown? Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{(-x)^{2016}e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1} \neq \frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x+1}$. Find the correct simplification and finish the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} \ dx &= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{x^{2016}e^x}{e^x + 1} + \frac{(-x)^{2016}e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1}\right)dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} x^{2016} \left(\frac{e^x}{e^x + 1} + \frac{1}{e^{x}+1}\right) dx \\
 &= \int_{0}^{1} x^{2016} \ dx=\frac1{2017}
\end{align*}